# jquery get elements, make them variables and change their content

Tags: jquery

im altering a forum site that show many threads and some replies for each one. all threads use same class names for different parts

so i managed to delete them with delete() but i cant do things like html() and append()

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(classo);
for (var n = elements.length; n--> 0;) 
    {
      var elementi = elements[n];

      elementi.remove(); < remove works but 
      elementi.html(...
     and elementi.append(...  < these 2 dont



    }
```

any ideas? thanks in advance

PS:
i dont use elementi.remove(); when trying to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Because dom elements does not have methods like `html()` or `append()` those are provided by jQuery, so you need to access the jQuery wrapper object of the dom element reference to access those methods

```
//use class selector to get the methods
var elements = $('.' + classo);
//use .each() from jQuery to iterate through the elements
elements.each(function () {
    //gets the jQuery wrapper object for the current dom element
    var elementi = $(this);

    elementi.remove(); < remove works but
    //all jQuery methods can be called on elementi
    elementi.html() //
    elementi.append() //
})
```

Comment: now.. to "access the jQuery wrapper object of the dom element reference "...hmm?.. im a noob

Answer (score 0):

You removes element and then fill it with some new? Element is absent after `delete()`.
seems you dont need this line

```
elementi.remove(); < remove works but
```

just replace content with `elementi.html(...`

Answer (score 0):

You can't append text to variable with append function.
Do it like this:

```
elementi += x;
```

Comment: elementi += ".append('stuff')"; ?

Comment: x is content which you want to append to elementi variable. elementi+=stuff;

Comment: Look at this fiddle. May be this will help you cause I'm not sure what do you want exactly. http://jsfiddle.net/XkyH7/